# How can I get an element component in aura:iteration

Tags: lightninginput, aura-iteration

I have an aura:iteration like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.lsFactorItems}" var="item">
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
  <lightning:input
   aura:id="fromInputField"
   value="{!item.From__c}"
   required="true"
   label="From"
   type="number"
   variant="label-stacked"
   onchange="{!c.onFromChange}"
  />
 </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

And its controller:

```
  onFromChange: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('onFromChange: ');
    var inputField = cmp.find("fromInputField");
    // want to get the input Component that's being changed here
  },
```

When I use `cmp.find("fromInputField")`, it will return an array of components. Is there anyway that I can get exactly the input component that I need? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`event.target` is the instance of the component currently being modified. It will be a [SecureComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_secure_component.htm). You should be able to get any attribute you'd like with either `event.target.getElement()[htmlProperty]`, `event.target.get("v.attributeName")`, and for dataset properties, `event.target.dataset[propertyName]`. See also [SecureComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_component.htm).